# Unexpected end of JSON input - Error message when requesting API data from FPL Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I trying to learn JavaScript, specifically node.js with express. While working on a personal project to get to grips with the language I have been trying to set up an API connection with https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/.

My aim is to eventually have a platform whereby you can request data from this and a number of other API's to create a live table for Fantasy Premier League.

While trying to set the connection up using https.get, I am getting an error message at the parsing stage when I go to request a specific piece of information (for example events[0].name would ideally return "Gameweek 1").

I have attached the code that I have used - the error message I am receiving is "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");

const app = express();


app.get("/", function(req, res){

    const url = "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/"

    https.get(url, function (response){
        console.log(response.statusCode);

        response.on("data", function(data){
            const fplData = JSON.parse(data)
            const gameweek = fplData.events[0].name
            console.log(gameweek)
        })
    })

    res.send("Server is working");

})

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server is running")
})
```

I have entered npm init, pip install express --save and installed body-parser into the command line prior to running the code.

Any help would be great, cheers

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: what console status code do you get back?

Comment: crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. I believe. The API works perfectly direct through the browser and on postman.

Comment: `response.on("data"` - this triggers when there is *some* data, not when there is necessarily *all* the data.  You are taking an incomplete fragment of the endpoint response and trying to json.parse it.

Comment: Any idea on how I can cater for this? I am reading about potentially using await/async functions @James

Comment: take a look at how `rawData` is used in [this example](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_url_options_callback)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your api is not returning well formed json. it says syntax error, because you are probably getting back an html error page in the response. At least, for me, that is almost always why i get this message.

In order, to verify if this is your issue. Try calling your API directly via a browser if it is a `GET` request. or via `postman` or `curl`